# Permissions required to use Microsoft.Web.Administration

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, iis-7

I'm trying to use IIS 7 management API but stuck with a security issue. My application is regular ASP.NET site running on .NET 4 (integrated pipeline). The machine is Windows 7 x64 (the app pool is default, running under ApplicationPoolIdentity, x64). The site uses the following settings:

```
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

My site tries to read other site's details via IIS management API (at localhost). I'm logged in as a member of local Administrators. In IE i try to open my page but get this:

```
Site 'mysite' at 'myhost' is unknown.System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) 
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.IAppHostProperty.get_Value() 
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement.GetPropertyValue(IAppHostProperty property) 
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site.get_State()
```

I don't understand why. I'm damn sure the code runs in impersonation context of my account (can see this is debugger watching `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal`). What am i doing wrong?

p.s.

UAC is on, but i believe that's not important.
Checked NTFS permissions on C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config folder - full access for Administrators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UAC is indeed the root of all evil. Impersonation behavior is broken when it's on. Something is really over-complicated here :(

When UAC is enabled and the current security context is impersonated, the principal reports he's not a member of local Administrators group. But he is. It has something to do with interactive/non-interactive sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Try set temp directory into web.config to folder with full permissions.

```
<compilation tempDirectory="c:\temp" ... ></compilation>
```